# Signaling an update in a tree structure

Tags: tree, structure

I have a tree structure that can periodically update ( meaning adding new elements inside the tree structure ). These updates can be performed at leaf level so I'm not sure where to signal that there is a new element somewhere in the tree. Should I have a "New" tag at each level down to the actual new element? I'm kind of stuck.

I think it's too much to show the "Updated" tag on each parent down to the leaf node. Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep the alert tag for the element that really needs it, the new one. The rest are just wrappers that don't need more than a simple indicator.

In the example image, the contrast is highlighted with a typographic style by changing the updated elements to bold.

[image]